# Sorting Rails query results in a specific order and adding the rest to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a specific order in which I want to show a number of my blog posts, but I'd also like to display regular blog posts after those selected ones.

So let's say I have posts [1, 7, 35, 36, 48] which I want to go first:

```
@selected_posts = Post.find([1, 7, 35, 36, 48])
```

But now I need to query for every other post, **excluding** those above:

```
@other_posts = Post.where.not(id: [1, 7, 35, 36, 48])
```

And now I need to combine those to maintain that order:

```
Post.find([1, 7, 35, 36, 48]) + Post.where.not(id: [1, 7, 35, 36, 48])
```

I'm using Postgres. Is it possible to do this in one query?

Comment: So you basically need one relation with the posts that match specific id list at the beginning, right?

Comment: yes sir, exactly. I'm querying twice, but maybe could be done in one pretty call? Not to mention that query I do to get the selected posts.

Comment: It's not as simple as it seems, but perhaps you will find answer here:
https://gist.github.com/cpjolicoeur/3590737

Comment: @MarekLipka this actually worked with array_position. Feel free to post that as the final answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can do order by case...

```
priority_ids = [1, 7, 35, 36, 48]

@all_posts = Post.all.order("CASE WHEN id IN (#{priority_ids.join(',')}) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END")
```

(thanks to @DeepakMahakale for correction)

Comment: It's generating wrong query `SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  ORDER BY case when required_course_id in (?) then 1 else 2 end, 1, 7, 35, 36, 48`

Comment: You will need to interpolate it

Comment: `Post.all.order("CASE WHEN id IN (#{priority_ids.join(',')}) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END")` This one generates
`SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  ORDER BY CASE WHEN id IN (1,7,35,36,48) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END`

Comment: By the way I like the approach

Comment: @DeepakMahakale thanks for the suggestion, will update answer.